# Get subtraction done through mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below mentioned table called myData1

```
ID   Value
1     150
2     120
3     100
```

I could get the last two values using below query:

```
SELECT value from myData1 order by ID desc limit 2;
```

I need to get the subtraction total of these two values (in this result set the result should be 100-120==> -20

Appreciate if someone can help to get this result

Comment: What have you tried so far? http://www.geeksengine.com/database/basic-select/arithmetic-operations.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Approach 1

- Use [Correlated Subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html) to get the first and second last value as two separate columns.
- You can then use the result-set as [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), to compute the difference.

Try (**[DB Fiddle DEMO #1](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j6S2o81vDkjPHGKzxbmGkA/0)**):

```
SELECT dt.last_value - dt.second_last_value 
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    t1.Value as last_value, 
    (SELECT t2.Value  
     FROM myData1 AS t2
     WHERE t2.ID < t1.ID 
     ORDER BY t2.ID DESC LIMIT 1) AS second_last_value
  FROM myData1 AS t1 
  ORDER BY t1.ID DESC LIMIT 1
) AS dt
```

---

### Approach 2

- Break into two different Select Queries; Use `Limit` with `Offset`. For last item, use a factor of **1**. For second last, use the factor of **-1**.
- Combine these results using `UNION ALL` into a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html).
- Eventually, sum the values using respective factors.

You can do the following (**[DB Fiddle DEMO #2](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/23yfrN9w7MrPQHkpdgkChY/0)**):

```
SELECT SUM(dt.factor * dt.Value) 
FROM 
(
  (SELECT Value, 1 AS factor 
   FROM myData1 
   ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0,1)

  UNION ALL

  (SELECT Value, -1 AS factor 
   FROM myData1 
   ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1,1)
) AS dt
```

Comment: @IsharaKularatna what is the issue. Why is it not working ? Please be more specific.

Comment: @IsharaKularatna I have added one more approach. Check Approach #1 also

Comment: @IsharaKularatna I have fixed the Approach #2 . just some parentheses were required around the two separate select queries.

Comment: @IsharaKularatna check these two DB fiddles for two different approaches: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j6S2o81vDkjPHGKzxbmGkA/0  and  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/23yfrN9w7MrPQHkpdgkChY/0